# How to get rows with a date is less than 30 days in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table structure:

Table: `tbl_CustomerPromos`:

```
COLUMN       DATATYPE
PromoCodeID  int (IDENTITY)
CustomerID   int
PromoCode    nvarchar(50)
AddedDate    DateTime
IsPromoUsed  smallint
```

I want to send email notification to all customers **AFTER EVERY 7 days from the DAY of JOINING (`AddedDate`) until the next 30 days.**

```
select 
   pc.[CustomerID]
   , pc.[PromoCode]
   , pc.[DiscountAmount]
   , ISNULL(pc.[IsPromoUsed], 0) IsPromoUsed
   , pc.[AddedBy]
   , pc.[AddedDate]
   , (c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName) FullName
   , c.Email
from 
   tbl_PromoCodesNewCustomer pc
Left join 
   tbl_Customers c on pc.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
Where 
   isnull(pc.IsPromoUsed, 0) <> 1
   AND pc.AddedDate = ?
```

**NOTE:** The 30days is to be counted from the day of joining (`AddedDate`) to next 30 days and not from joining month.

So, how to get rows with a date that is less than 30 days (`AddedDate` is not greater than 30 days from today's date)

Comment: What exactly do you need ? The rows which are 7,14,21,28 days old or all rows that are less than 30 days old ?

Comment: well both conditions needs to satisfy..! as @StuartLC got it correctly that is what i mean to say...! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the 'every 7 days' filter, I would suggest you MODULO the date diff (after checking that its within the 30 day period). A CTE will help DRY this up. Also, I'm assuming here that you'll only be running this exactly once per day.

```
WITH EligiblePromoCodes AS
(
   SELECT 
      CustomerId,
      PromoCode,
      IsPromoUsed,
      DiscountAmount,
      AddedDate,
      AddedBy,
      DATEDIFF(dd, AddedDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS DaysSinceAdded
   FROM
     tbl_PromoCodesNewCustomer
)
SELECT
   pc.[CustomerID]
   , pc.[PromoCode]
   , pc.[DiscountAmount]
   , ISNULL(pc.[IsPromoUsed], 0) IsPromoUsed
   , pc.[AddedBy]
   , pc.[AddedDate]
   , (c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName) FullName
   , c.Email
from 
   EligiblePromoCodes pc
Left join 
   tbl_Customers c on pc.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
Where 
   isnull(pc.IsPromoUsed, 0) <> 1
   AND DaysSinceAdded <= 30 
   AND DaysSinceAdded % 7 = 0;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9fed2/3)

Answer (score 1):

Try lyk this

```
select ..
from table
where datediff(dd,AddedDate,getdate())<30 and ..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select pc.[CustomerID]
    ,pc.[PromoCode]
    ,pc.[DiscountAmount]
    ,isnull(pc.[IsPromoUsed],0)IsPromoUsed
    ,pc.[AddedBy]
    ,pc.[AddedDate]
    ,(c.FirstName +' '+ c.LastName)FullName
    ,c.Email
from tbl_PromoCodesNewCustomer pc
Left join tbl_Customers c
on pc.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
Where isnull(pc.IsPromoUsed,0)<>1
AND datediff(dd,pc.AddedDate,getdate())<30 order by pc.AddedDate desc
```